# XSLT: Sorting items by multiple characteristics

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to sort all the section separately by period (moth,day,week,years...). Somme section have the same period.
i don't understand how to add the distinctions of year and month

I have XML data such as:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <chapter>

<title>Title of chapter </title>

<section>
<title> Title of section 2</title>
<para>Period is 2 year </para>
</section>
<section>
<title> Title of section 1</title>
<para>Period is 1 year </para>
</section>
<section>
<title> Title of section 3</title>
<para>Period is 1 week </para>
</section>
<section>
<title> Title of section 4</title>
<para>Period is 1 year </para>
</section>

</chapter>
```

And I need the result like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<chapter>

<title>Title of chapter </title>
<section>
<title> List elem of 1 week</title>
<section>
<title> Title of section 3</title>
<para>Period is 1 week </para>
</section>
</section>

<section>
<title> List elem of 1 year</title>
<section>
<title> Title of section 1</title>
<para>Period is 1 year </para>
</section>
<section>
<title> Title of section 4</title>
<para>Period is 1 year </para>
</section>
</section>

<section>
<title> List elem of 2 years </title>
<section>
<title> Title of section 2</title>
<para>Period is 2 years </para>
</section>
</section>

</chapter>
```

And my XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node(  ) | @*"> 
        <xsl:copy>  
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node(  )"/>  
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>     
    <xsl:variable name="liste_valeurs" select="//para[not(. = preceding::para)]"/>

    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <xsl:copy> 

            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$liste_valeurs">
                    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="valeur" select="."/>
                    <xsl:element name="section">
                        <title> List elem of <xsl:value-of select="$valeur"/></title>           
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//para[.=$valeur]">
                            <xsl:call-template name="copie_identique"/>                             
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:element>                  

                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="copie_identique">
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And i'm not getting the expected result, i'm pretty new to XSLT and forgive me if the answer already exists, i searched but i'm a little lost and i don't know exactly what to search.

I don't know where to go and maybe the method isn't the best way to achieve what i want.

Thank you for any help you can provide,

Comment: Does every `para` follow the same pattern of `"Period is <<number>> <<period>> "`?

Comment: Yes all @para follow the same pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not simple. Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<chapter>
  <title>Title of chapter </title>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 1</title>
    <para>Period is 2 years </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 2</title>
    <para>Period is 3 weeks </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 3</title>
    <para>Period is 10 months </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 4</title>
    <para>Period is 1 year </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 5</title>
    <para>Period is 1 week </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 6</title>
    <para>Period is 2 months </para>
  </section>
</chapter>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="section">
                <xsl:sort select="number(contains(para, 'week'))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="number(contains(para, 'month'))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="number(contains(para, 'year'))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="translate(para, translate(para, '0123456789', ''), '')" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter>
  <title>Title of chapter </title>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 5</title>
    <para>Period is 1 week </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 2</title>
    <para>Period is 3 weeks </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 6</title>
    <para>Period is 2 months </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 3</title>
    <para>Period is 10 months </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 4</title>
    <para>Period is 1 year </para>
  </section>
  <section>
    <title> Title of section 1</title>
    <para>Period is 2 years </para>
  </section>
</chapter>
```

---

If you want to group the `section`s by `para`, then study the [Muenchian method](http://%3C?xml%20version=%221.0%22%20encoding=%22UTF-8%22?%3E%20%3Cchapter%3E%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ETitle%20of%20chapter%20%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%3Csection%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%20Title%20of%20section%205%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%3EPeriod%20is%201%20week%20%3C/para%3E%20%20%20%3C/section%3E%20%20%20%3Csection%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%20Title%20of%20section%202%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%3EPeriod%20is%203%20weeks%20%3C/para%3E%20%20%20%3C/section%3E%20%20%20%3Csection%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%20Title%20of%20section%206%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%3EPeriod%20is%202%20months%20%3C/para%3E%20%20%20%3C/section%3E%20%20%20%3Csection%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%20Title%20of%20section%203%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%3EPeriod%20is%2010%20months%20%3C/para%3E%20%20%20%3C/section%3E%20%20%20%3Csection%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%20Title%20of%20section%204%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%3EPeriod%20is%201%20year%20%3C/para%3E%20%20%20%3C/section%3E%20%20%20%3Csection%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3E%20Title%20of%20section%201%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%3EPeriod%20is%202%20years%20%3C/para%3E%20%20%20%3C/section%3E%20%3C/chapter%3E).